# Android environment setup script

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

We are setting up a CI machine and want to setup the android environment via script.

Is there any script to install android sdks, setup the environment variables start emulators and accept sdk licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`EnvInject`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Plugin to achieve what you want. This will give you an option to run a script, before build so that you can configure what you want. It will also have an option to `Keep Jenkins Environment Variables` or not. Hope this helps.